# How to guarantee that I get the `HTREEITEM` for the item that the user right-clicked on in a CTreeControl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a window which has a `CTreeCtrl`. A user can right-click any element and display a context menu. From there they can choose to delete the entry. Something like this:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the context menu item handler:

```
void CAssignHistoryDlg::OnDeleteFromAssignmentHistory()
{
    CString         strINI = theApp.GetAssignHistoryPath();
    HTREEITEM       hItem = m_treeHistory.GetSelectedItem();
    CString         strName, strDeletedName, strEntry;

    if (m_treeHistory.GetParentItem(hItem) != nullptr)
    {
        // The user has picked one of the history dates.
        // So the parent should be the actual name.
        hItem = m_treeHistory.GetParentItem(hItem);

        // Now OK to proceed
    }

    strName = ExtractName(hItem);

    GetParent()->EnableWindow(FALSE);
    strEntry.Format(IDS_TPL_SURE_DELETE_FROM_ASSIGN_HIST, strName);
    if (AfxMessageBox(strEntry, MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDNO)
    {
```

The image shows my problem. If I **first** click on **Test**, so that **it is selected** and bright blue and **then** right-click, it shows **Test** in the popup message. This is fine. But ...

If the **first name** is **initially selected**, and I go ahead and **directly right-click Test**, even though it seems to go blue (as if selected), `m_treeHistory.GetSelectedItem()` is returning the original, first name. I think I am describing it not very well.

In short, *I want to guarantee that I get the `HTREEITEM` for the item that the user right-clicked on*. What I have is not 100% fool-proof.

If it helps, this is how I display the context menu:

```
void CAssignHistoryDlg::OnNMRclickTreeHistory(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    CMenu           mnuContext, *pMnuEdit = nullptr;
    CPoint          ptLocal;
    LPNMTREEVIEW    pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    GetCursorPos(&ptLocal);

    mnuContext.LoadMenu( IDR_MENU_SM_ASSIGN_HIST_POPUP );
    pMnuEdit = mnuContext.GetSubMenu( 0 );
    if (pMnuEdit != nullptr)
    {
        pMnuEdit->TrackPopupMenu( TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_LEFTBUTTON,
                    ptLocal.x, ptLocal.y, this, nullptr );
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

So to recap, at the moment the user must physically left click on a item in the tree to select it. Then they can right-click and it will offer to delete this person. But if they go ahead and just right-click on anyone, it will not offer to delete THAT person.

Comment: I have located this article and am reading through it. https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/misc-advanced/article.php/c691/Right-button-popup-menu.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the *actual* tree item at any given point using the [`HitTest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class?view=vs-2019#hittest) member of the `CTreeCtrl` class. Exactly how and *where* you do this will depend on your code design but, if you have a pointer to your `CTreeCtrl` (`pwTree` in the code below), then you can do something like this:

```cpp
CPoint ptLocal;
GetCursorPos(&ptLocal);
pWTree->ScreenToClient(&ptLocal); // May not be required in certain handlers?
HTREEITEM hItem = pWTree->HitTest(ptLocal); // Remember to check for NULL return!
```

You can then either use the returned `hItem` directly, or use it to *explicitly* set the tree's selection (to that item), before doing any further processing.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. However, I had to cache the `CPoint` in my `OnNMRclickTreeHistory` handler into a variable. And then, use that as you indicated. This is because the menu item itself is offset down and to the right, so the `HitTest` response is the wrong item. By caching the point in the right-click handler and subsequently using that it always yeils the correct item! Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

The MS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019 doesn't have a "click" handler, it has `CWnd::OnRButtonDblClk`, `CWnd::OnRButtonDown` and `CWnd::OnRButtonUp`. Which one are you handling?

The reason for your defect might be that you don't let the tree control handle that right button event (to select that new item).

I would suggest to use `CWnd::OnContextMenu` instead.

Comment: Hi. The accepted answer was the solution. I use NM_RCLICK. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-rclick-list-view

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - even if that solved your problem, it's hardly a solution; kludge at best. You are deleting an item that cursor points to at the time `OnDeleteFromAssignmentHistory` was called, that may or may not be the sane item that was selected when the menu was invoked. I would try to figure out why the expected selection doesn't match the actual one, and I think my proposal would *really* solve this problem.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - I did a little testing, and it appears that Right Click by itself does NOT change the selection in the CTreeCtrl; you could find which item is under the cursor and call `CTreeCtrl::SelectItem()`. I truly believe that this is the correct way to handle selection.

Comment: For example: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/222/Q222905/

Comment: Also, did you not read my comment to the answer I accepted? I cache the point they click on at the time the menu is displayed. I use that position and not the position where they click a menu item. It is not a kludge.

Comment: Please see the knowledgebase article. Even if I used `ContextMenu` I still need the event handler I am using now. What's more, I still need to use `HitTest`. So the accepted answer (taken with my comment to that answer) is not a kludge and is correct.

Comment: Last two points, I promise :) (1) you said `even though it seems to go blue (as if selected),`, so you *assumed* that right-click selects the item; why not do that? (2) you may (or will in the future) have a main menu item (or accelerator) that does the same; who would set up the cache then? It really is easier to *ALWAYS* perform commands on *selected* item, and to make sure the selection matches your expectations.

Comment: Have you actually read the knowledge base article? It uses the handler that I am using, and it gets the mouse position in that handler. It them simulates a content menu handler with that info and posts the message. You then use `HitTest`. This is not a normal situation. This is a `CTreeCtrl` and it is not the same. I appreciate you answering, but the guidance is clear. Can we please leave it at that? Thanks.